# Multiple event handlers on dynamic content with .on()

Tags: jquery

We can attach multiple events to an element using `.on()`

```
$('.foo').on({
    'click':function(e){
        // do stuff
    },
    'mouseenter':function(e){
        // do some other stuff
    },
    'mouseleave':function(e){
        // do completely different stuff
    }
});
```

We can also attach a handler to the document and filter for our elements to have the event on subsequently created elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo', function(e){
    // do stuff
});
```

Is it possible to combine these behaviours to bind multiple events to an element and future elements?

Comment: Different function bodies?

Comment: If you're asking can you provide an object to the delegated `on` handler, then the answer is no. You have to call it once for each event type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes;

```
$(document).on({
    'click':function(e){
        // do stuff
    },
    'mouseenter':function(e){
        // do some other stuff
    },
    'mouseleave':function(e){
        // do completely different stuff
    }
}, '.foo');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ktybjprh/

This is covered by the [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) signature, available as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: Awesome! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```js
$(document).on({
    click: function() {
        alert("click")
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
        alert("mouseenter")
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        alert("mouseleave")
    }
}, ".foo");
```

```html
<div class="foo">test</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <p class="foo" style="height: 30px;width: 40px;">Test</p>
<script>
   $(".foo").on('mouseenter click mouseleave', function (event) {
      alert('ok')
    });
  </script>
```